# Best UX online courses and certificates for a software developer

Tags: interaction-design, ux-designer, interactive-ui

What are some of the good online courses that I can take, to expand my knowledge with UX/UI design? I know this is a broad subject, but suggestions on a good course to get me started would be great.

Comment: if you are looking for courses covering all aspects try Interaction Design Foundation. Their courses are well structured, backed by experts, very very broad in type of topics, and well priced. It will get you going, but do understand it is not a replacement for a formal course in UX/UI.

Comment: This isn't a User Experience problem needing solving so I'm afraid it's not the right place to ask for such advice.

Answer (score 0):

I could not recommend more the [Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/training/) seminars. NNG is the very high top UX consulting agency. Since the beginning of the lockdown they switched (very effectively) to online format now.

I've been attending their offline and online courses for over 3 years now. Can't stress enough how insightful the classes are. Check it out!

Particularly for a software developer that would like to know more about UX (kudos for that btw) I would recommend their [Lean/Agile UX seminars](https://www.nngroup.com/online-seminars/topic/agile/) or anything you can find useful in their [seminars offering](https://www.nngroup.com/online-seminars/).